# Group child elements by partial value

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have this XML file:

```
<Elements>
  <Element name="A.B.C.x">
    <Child>...</Child>
    <Child>...</Child>
    <Child>...</Child>
  </Element>
  <Element name="A.B.C.y">
    <Child>...</Child>
    <Child>...</Child>
  </Element>
  <Element name="A.D.E.y">
    <Child>...</Child>
  </Element>
  <Element name="A.D.E.z">
    <Child>...</Child>
    <Child>...</Child>
    <Child>...</Child>
  </Element>
</Elements>
```

I need to create XSL to get this result:

```
<Elements>
  <Element name="A.B.C">
    <LastToken name="x" childCount="3" />
    <LastToken name="y" childCount="2" />
  </Element>
  <Element name="A.D.E">
    <LastToken name="y" childCount="1" />
    <LastToken name="z" childCount="3" />
  </Element>
</Elements>
```

I am limited to XSL 1.0 with no extensions and I cannot figure out how to achieve the result.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** As some answers came in I saw I have to clarify my question/task:
Tokens in `name` attribute of `Element` node are not limited to one character. Sample value of 'name' attribute could be `This.Is.Grouping.Target.AndThisIsGroupChild`

Comment: Excellent question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution which only makes a minimal assumption on the format of the `name` attribute's value.

Comment: Also added an XSLT 2.0 solution, which has *no* assumptions on the format of the `name` attribute.

Comment: Completely replaced the XSLT 1.0 solution with one that doesn't assume anything -- this is a complete solution of the most general case!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun, a general XSLT 1.0 solution without extensions:

```
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [
  <!ENTITY key "
substring(
   @name,
   1,
   string-length(
      @name
   )
 - count(
      document('')//node()[
         not(
            contains(
               substring(
                  current()/@name,
                  string-length(
                     current()/@name
                  )
                - position()
                + 1
               ),
               '.'
            )
         )
      ]
   )
 - 1
)">
]>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kElementByNamePrefix" match="Element" use="&key;"/>
    <xsl:key name="kElementByName" match="Element" use="@name"/>
    <xsl:template match="Element">
        <xsl:variable name="vNamePrefix" select="&key;"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vCurrentGroup"
         select="key('kElementByNamePrefix',$vNamePrefix)"/>
        <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id($vCurrentGroup[1])">
            <Element name="{$vNamePrefix}">
                <xsl:apply-templates
                 select="$vCurrentGroup[
                            generate-id()
                          = generate-id(
                               key('kElementByName',@name)[1]
                            )
                         ]"
                 mode="prefix">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pNamePrefix" select="$vNamePrefix"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </Element>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Element" mode="prefix">
        <xsl:param name="pNamePrefix"/>
        <LastToken name="{substring(substring-after(@name,$pNamePrefix),2)}"
                   childCount="{count(key('kElementByName',@name)/Child)}"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Element name="A.B.C">
    <LastToken name="x" childCount="3" />
    <LastToken name="y" childCount="2" />
</Element>
<Element name="A.D.E">
    <LastToken name="y" childCount="1" />
    <LastToken name="z" childCount="3" />
</Element>
```

Comment: @Ramunas: You are welcome. Do check for your XSLT processor's `node-set()` extension function implementation any way. Composition is one the most useful patterns in declarative paradigm.

Answer (score 2):

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation** (absolutely no limitations):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
 exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kElemByName" match="Element"
          use="@name"/>

 <xsl:key name="klastTokenByName" match="@lastToken"
  use="../@name"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Element/@name">
  <xsl:attribute name="name">
   <xsl:call-template name="init"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="lastToken">
   <xsl:call-template name="lastToken"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="pass2"
      select="ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)/*"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template mode="pass2" match="Element"/>

 <xsl:template mode="pass2" match=
  "Element[generate-id()
          =
           generate-id(key('kElemByName',@name)[1])
          ]
  ">
  <Element name="{@name}">
    <xsl:for-each select=
    "key('klastTokenByName',@name)">

     <lastToken name="{.}"
       childCount="{count(key('kElemByName',../@name)
                               [@lastToken=current()]
                                 /Child
                          )
                    }"
     />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </Element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="lastToken">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
  <xsl:param name="pDelim" select="'.'"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vrtfTokens">
   <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$pText"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pDelim" select="$pDelim"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:value-of select=
   "ext:node-set($vrtfTokens)/*[last()]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="init">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
  <xsl:param name="pDelim" select="'.'"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vLastToken">
    <xsl:call-template name="lastToken">
     <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$pText"/>
     <xsl:with-param name="pDelim" select="$pDelim"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:value-of select=
   "substring($pText,
              1,
               string-length($pText)
              - string-length($vLastToken)
              - string-length($pDelim)
              )
   "/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="tokenize">
  <xsl:param name="pText"/>
  <xsl:param name="pDelim" select="'.'"/>

  <xsl:if test="string-length($pText)">
    <token>
     <xsl:value-of select=
      "substring-before(concat($pText,$pDelim),
                        $pDelim)"/>
    </token>
    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
     <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
     "substring-after($pText,$pDelim)"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Elements>
    <Element name="A.B.C.x">
        <Child>...</Child>
        <Child>...</Child>
        <Child>...</Child>
    </Element>
    <Element name="A.B.C.y">
        <Child>...</Child>
        <Child>...</Child>
    </Element>
    <Element name="A.D.E.y">
        <Child>...</Child>
    </Element>
    <Element name="A.D.E.z">
        <Child>...</Child>
        <Child>...</Child>
        <Child>...</Child>
    </Element>
</Elements>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<Elements>
   <Element name="A.B.C">
      <lastToken name="x" childCount="3"/>
      <lastToken name="y" childCount="2"/>
   </Element>
   <Element name="A.D.E">
      <lastToken name="y" childCount="1"/>
      <lastToken name="z" childCount="3"/>
   </Element>
</Elements>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, Dimitre. Unfortunately tokens in `name` attribute a delimited by dots and can exceed one character. Sorry I did not make it clear in my question (edited).

Comment: @Ramunas: Replaced the solution with a most general one -- no limitations assumed. This is the solution you need. :)

Comment: `Namespace 'http://exslt.org/common' does not contain any functions.` Do you have any idea why I get this?

Answer (score 1):

**An XSLT 2.0 solution** (absolutely no limitations assumed):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="xs my"
    >
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:for-each-group select="/*/*"
        group-by="substring(@name, 1,
                             string-length(@name)
                            - string-length(my:LastToken(@name)) -1)">
      <xsl:variable name="vLastToken"
           select="my:LastToken(@name)"/>
      <Element name="{substring(@name,1,
                                  string-length(@name)
                                 -
                                   string-length($vLastToken)-1)}">

       <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()"
        group-by="my:LastToken(@name)">

        <xsl:variable name="vLastToken" select="my:LastToken(@name)"/>

        <LastToken name="{$vLastToken}"
                   childCount="{count(current-group()/Child)}"/>
       </xsl:for-each-group>

      </Element>
     </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:function name="my:LastToken" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:param name="pText" as="xs:string"/>

  <xsl:sequence select="tokenize($pText, '\.')[last()]"/>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Elements>
    <Element name="A.B.C.x">
        <Child>...</Child>
        <Child>...</Child>
        <Child>...</Child>
    </Element>
    <Element name="A.B.C.y">
        <Child>...</Child>
        <Child>...</Child>
    </Element>
    <Element name="A.D.E.y">
        <Child>...</Child>
    </Element>
    <Element name="A.D.E.z">
        <Child>...</Child>
        <Child>...</Child>
        <Child>...</Child>
    </Element>
</Elements>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<Element name="A.B.C">
   <LastToken name="x" childCount="3"/>
   <LastToken name="y" childCount="2"/>
</Element>
<Element name="A.D.E">
   <LastToken name="y" childCount="1"/>
   <LastToken name="z" childCount="3"/>
</Element>
```

Comment: This would be a perfect solution for me if I was not bound to XSL 1.0.

Comment: @Ramunas: You have tagged your question also with "xquery" and xquery uses XPath 2.0. Would an XQuery solution really be useful to you?

Comment: I guess only as much as XSL processor can make use of it (if at all). XSL is not my strongest skill so I cannot tell if two can live together and help each other. Basically I have XML and have to create XSL to transform XML to a desired format using XSL 1.0 processor.

Comment: @Ramunas: No problem, see my latest most general and completely assumptions-free XSLT 1.0 solution.

Comment: `Namespace 'http://exslt.org/common' does not contain any functions.` Do you have any idea why I get this?

Comment: @Ramunas: Yes. The `xxx:node-set()` extension function is vendor-specific. Every XSLT vendor has their oun namespace (and in the case of Xalan - even different name) for this function. In my solution I am using the `ext:node-set()` function in the EXSLT namespace, because most XSLT 1.0 processors implement EXSLT. If your XSLT processor doesn't support EXSLT then you need to find out what namespace this function is in. For MSXML the namespace is: "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt".

Comment: @Ramunas: Did you find what is your XSLT processor and what is its xxx:node-set() extension function? You need to know this not only for the solution of this problem. In practice most more-or-less difficult problems in XSLT 1.0 are solved using the xxx:node-set() extension. Also, do find out whether your XSLT processor supports (any subset of) EXSLT.

Comment: @Dimitre: I am using `msxsl.exe` util (can't find link describing it). I guess it's from Microsoft and I guess it uses MSXML.

Comment: @Ramunas: Then you should define this namespace: `xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"` and replace `ext:node-set()` with `msxsl:node-set()`. And use the simpler solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/index.xml):

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="Element" use="substring(@name, 1, 5)"/>

<xsl:key name="k2" match="Element" use="@name"/>

<xsl:template match="Elements">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Element[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', substring(@name, 1, 5))[1])]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Element">
  <Element name="{substring(@name, 1, 5)}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('k1', substring(@name, 1, 5))[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k2', @name)[1])]" mode="token">
      <xsl:sort select="substring(@name, 7)"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </Element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Element" mode="token">
  <LastToken name="{substring(@name, 7)}" childCount="{count(key('k2', @name)/Child)}"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sorry I did not make it clear in my question that `substring()` is not a solution for me.